# Windows 2012 R2 build server - IE 11 Selenium (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm creating automation tests in C# and .NET 4.5 and SpecFlow + NUnit

My ASP.NET MVC application has Kendo MVC controls. On one of the pages there is a JavaScript variable that we create to indicate that all client side Kendo fields are loaded.

From one of my NUnit tests has C# code to read the value of the client side variable using below script:

```
public override void EnsurePageReady()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                var fieldsLoaded = WebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<bool>("return kendoFieldsLoaded;");
                if (fieldsLoaded)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        } while (true);
    }
```

The ExecuteJavaScript() works fine locally in all three major browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE11). However I get UnexpectedJavaScriptError) on the Build Server with Windows Server 2012 R2 and IE11 on Windows 10.

I've tried all the suggestion on the Internet including Registry changes, Enabling protected Mode etc, but no luck.

I'm hitting a wall and I would appreciate any help or pointers that I can get to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Correction: Works on IE11 locally not on the Build server with Win 2012 R2

Comment: I know this is very vague, but it seems like its a security setting on the target machine. What is your Enhanced Security setting set to?

Comment: Do you still get the error with `return true;` instead of `return kendoFieldsLoaded;` ?

Comment: Hi Moe - Where is that setting?

Comment: Hi Florent - Yes, same result. Something about Windows 2012 R2 + IE11, works fine on Windows 10 + IE11

Comment: https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to disable the enhanced security settings on a windows 2012 R2,
Here is the link on how to do so:

https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/